# How to convert a CatPart file to STL format in python?

Tags: python, 3d, cad

I'm trying to convert a CatPart file to stl format in python. I found the Pycatia library, but it only works with Catia V5 installed. Is there any other way to convert CatParts to STL directly or indirectly in Python?